# How to get the values in $_POST array from the fields which are appended to the HTML table using JQuery after form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

I've one HTML form. This form is containing HTML table. The actual HTML table is very large. For your reference I'm showing below the HTML code of a form with tablw containing only two records:

```
<form action="rebates.php" role="form" method="post">
  <div style="margin-left: 12px" class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="company_name" class="col-lg-4">Manufacturer </label>
      <div class="col-lg-7">
        <select id="company_name" name="company_name" class="form-control">
          <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Manufacturer</option>
          <option value="33" >Eywa Solutions</option>
          <option value="37" >Amazon</option>
          <option value="40" >Test</option>
          <option value="42" >RK</option>
          <option value="46" >Santa Margherita</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div style="margin-left: -61px" class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="product_id" class="col-lg-3">Product </label>
        <div class="col-lg-7">
          <select id="product_id" name="product_id" class="form-control">
            <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Product</option>
            <option value="5" >Chesse</option>
            <option value="8" >Laptop an</option>
            <option value="9" >Prosecco</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/> 
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>            
  <div class="col-md-8">   
    <div style="overflow:auto" class="well">      
      <button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
      <br/>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table   id="blacklistgrid"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr  id="Row1">
              <th style="vertical-align:middle" >Pack Of</th>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr id="Row2">
              <td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="2" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="750" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
              <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  Units
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Microsecond</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">oz</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ml</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">gms</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="amount[]" value="3.00" class="form-control" size="9"/>
              </td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="4" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="volume[]" value="750" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
              <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <select name="units[]" class="form-control">
                    <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
                    <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>
                    <option value="7" >oz</option>
                    <option value="9" >ml</option>
                    <option value="10" >L</option>
                    <option value="12" >gms</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td><input type="text" name="amount[]" value="7.00" class="form-control" size="9"/></td>
            </tr>                      
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button style="float:right" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-plus"></i> &nbsp;Add New Rebate</button>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /span8 -->    
    <div class="row">
      <div  class="col-xs-5"></div>
      <div style="margin-left: -9px"  class="col-xs-5">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Preview</button>
      </div>                
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm dynamically appending rows to the table by clicking on a button(the button is present in a  tag, you can see in above code). The jQuery code I writen for adding rows dynamically is as follows:

```
/*JQuery for appending rows at the end of table*/
<script language="javascript"> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.btnAdd').click(function () {
    var count = 1,
    first_row = $('#Row2');
    //while (count-- > 0) first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
      while (count-- > 0) first_row.clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
  });
});
</script>
```

Now the issue I'm facing is if I append one or more rows at the end of table, fill data in the textfields from each appended row and submit the form by clicking on Submit button, in `$_POST` I'm not able to get the data from appended rows. I'm getting the data only from the rows which are previously present when the page loads. So can anyone help me in getting the values from the dynamically appended rows also?

The HTMl code of dynamically appended table row is as follows:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" size="8" value="" name="pack[]">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" size="8" value="2" name="quantity[]">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" size="8" value="750" name="volume[]">
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
      Units
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Microsecond</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">oz</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">ml</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">L</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">gms</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" size="9" value="3.00" name="amount[]">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: OT: you should add the tr to the tbody, not to the table itself

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have done the right thing. Please see the name field of your input element.

```
<input type="text" name="pack[]" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/>
```

Please notice the `name="pack[]"` using an array of name as input. If you have cloned the table, the input element will be cloned. Since you aren't using an id, it's not a problem.

Now, when sending the data, in `rebates.php` check if the form data is present. It can be done by checking up the request method. It's a secure way. Once the check has succeeded, you can check if the field is present

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // handle the fields
    $packs = null;
    if (isset($_POST['pack']) {
        $packs = $_POST['pack'];
    }
}
```

Please notice that you are using `pack` *without* the `[]` to get input data from `pack[]` input fields. The variable `$pack` will contain an array. If you want to check the content, use `var_dump($pack);`. It should reveal all data from the available `pack[]` elements, either added dynamically or statically.

Then, if you have collected all data, you have to loop through it. It can be done with either for- or foreach-loop.

```
if ($packs != null) {
    foreach($packs as $pack) {
        // use the field $pack to do something
        echo 'amount of pack : ' . $pack;
    }
}
```

Do the same for other name fields which is also from array.

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery Doc:

> Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

You are cloning table row with #Row2 id. To avoid it:

```
first_row.clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('#blacklistgrid');
```

Comment: I tried your code but still the same result. Not getting values from dynamically appended rows. Do you have any other trick which would work?

Comment: yes, sure. I've modified my question you can see the code of dynamically appended table row in above question's body.

Comment: Hmm I've tested your code and it works fine for me. I've added 2 more rows and submited the form here is how my encoded POST looks like:

company_name=&product_id=&pack[]=&quantity[]=2&volume[]=750&amount[]=3.00&pack[]=&quantity[]=4&volume[]=750&units[]=&amount[]=7.00&pack[]=&quantity[]=2&volume[]=750&amount[]=999&pack[]=&quantity[]=2&volume[]=750&amount[]=888

I've modified the amount input, as you can see there are 2 values 888 and 999. 

I think the problem is in your PHP code.

Comment: How could this be possible that PHP code is having some problem? I'm just printing the $_POST nothing else than that.

Comment: Could you post here this: var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do something like...

```
while (count-- > 0) first_row.clone().appendTo('#blacklistgrid').attr('id','Row' +              $('#blacklistgrid tr').length);
```

Comment: I tried your code, but still the result is same. Not able to access the values from the dyanmically appneded row in $_POST. Do you have any other idea?